# How to populate all the listViews in click of a button?

Tags: android

I have three tabs with three screens A,B,C screens.The screen A has a listview and a download button, screen B has a different listview and screen C again has a differnt listView. In screen A when I am pressing the dowmnload button the database is getting populated and the ListView in Screen A is getting polpulated. I am trying to polpolte the other two screens as well when I am clicking on the download button but I am not able to do this.How can I polpulate all the three listviews on a single click of the button in scree A. Please help me out in doing this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should post some code or a little more details on what kind of information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a common data structure to populate all the three tabs ListView.

It will definitely solves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Create a constant `public static final int UPDATE_LIST = 100;`

Make all the adapters public.

Write Handler, where you will update the list and also call notifydatasetchanged method of adapter which will update the all list user will be able to see the change instantly

```
private Handler photoGridHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case UPDATE_LIST:

                update with listA, listB, listC

                // mThumbIds = addnewBitmapToTheList(bitMapImage, mThumbIds);
                adapterA.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapterB.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapterC.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // Log.e(TAG,"Image Array Size...."+searchDirectoryImgList.size());
                // Log.e(TAG,"Directory Found...."+CFMConstant.searchVector.size());
                break;


        };
    };

    }
```

on button click give call to handler so that the list will be updated. Use the following code.

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.what = UPDATE_LIST;
photoGridHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Comment: hi! deepak..I have different data Structure for all the three listViews.

Comment: differente data structure in the sense? Can you please ellaborate

Comment: I mean that I have differnt objects and tables for all the three listviews.